# JSP errorPage in production has exception 95% of cases null, what could be the underlying reason?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, error-handling, glassfish

Error page is configured as:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/common/general-error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/common/general-error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

General-error.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
  <%
  String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
  if (referer != null && !"null".equals(referer) && !referer.contains("googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead")) {
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).severe("GENERAL ERROR MESSAGE: requestUrl= " + request.getRequestURI() + "?" + request.getQueryString() 
          +  ",      referer:" + referer);
  }
if (exception != null) {
  Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR CAUSE:" +    exception.getMessage(), exception);
  }
```

Well apparently in our web application which gets around 20 requests per second, most logs don't contain `exception`. So `exception` is almost always null! I find it weird.

Any idea what could be underlying reason for this? We are using glassfish if that is of any importance.

BTW, referrer is printed correctly, snapshot from logs:

`[#|2013-10-31T02:32:55.903+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jsp.common.general_002derror_jsp|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GENERAL ERROR MESSAGE: requestUrl= /LivingCost/common/general-error.jsp?null,      referer:http://www.priceline.com/delta-grand-okanagen-resort-and-conference-centre-kelowna-british-columbia-BC-144934-hd.hotel-reviews-hotel-guides|#]`

[#|2013-10-31T02:37:23.471+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jsp.common.general_002derror_jsp|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GENERAL ERROR MESSAGE: requestUrl= /LivingCost/common/general-error.jsp?null,      referer:http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Taiwan|#]

[#|2013-10-31T02:37:23.663+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jsp.common.general_002derror_jsp|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GENERAL ERROR MESSAGE: requestUrl= /LivingCost/common/general-error.jsp?null,      referer:http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Taiwan|#]

Comment: why is that so !"null".equals(referer)?

Comment: Yes.referer  what is !"null".equals(referer) for ??
referer != null is enought.
Also please check that the request is getting and the string variable referer conatins value in it.U can dubug the application and check that.

Comment: `!"null".equals(referer)` is because we have some `dispatcher.jsp` which redirects and sets other referer, so that we can trace real referer. But most requests do not go through that dispatcher. Anyway, that doesn't hurt anything just could print less logs, which is not the case there are referer's printed but exceptions very rarely. Confused.